# How do I trigger an action after API call using redux-api-middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to use redux-api-middleware. I would like my app to POST a sign up request to an API and once it receives a response, trigger a function, similar to a .then() function. Something like this:

```
export const signUp = (user, functionToClearForm) => ({
  [RSAA]: {
    endpoint: '/api/users/',
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    types: [
        SIGNUP_REQUEST, SIGNUP_SUCCESS, SIGNUP_FAILURE
    ]
  }
  .then(functionToClearForm());
})
```

How do I do this? Is there any example or tutorial explaining how to trigger an action AFTER the API call is made. The only tutorials I found show how to update the state, but I don't want to update the state, I want to trigger an action.

Can this even be done use RSAA?

Comment: **RSAA**...what is it?

Comment: I'm not sure, it came from this tutorial: https://medium.com/@viewflow/full-stack-django-quick-start-with-jwt-auth-and-react-redux-part-ii-be9cf6942957

Answer (score 0):

You should use `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga` to make async calls.

Comment: It is a comment. do not post it as answer. You can find comment area below post.